# Intermittent lag from external keyboard and mouse

Tags: mac, keyboard, imac, usb, mouse

I have a 2018 MacBook Air, and an external Logitech keyboard and mouse. Every few minutes there will be a significant input lag from either the mouse or keyboard or both. Sometimes inputs just straight up won't register at all.

The laptop keyboard and trackpad both work fine, its just the external keyboard and mouse pair. They are connected via an wireless USB dongle, which I'm plugging in with a USB-C hub.

I've tried multiple hubs, so I'm sure that's not the problem. I've also tried a different mouse, which did had the same problems, so its not the peripherals.

Anyone encountered the same problem?

Comment: Does the lag occur if the USB dongle is directly connected to the MBA instead of through the hub?

Comment: What else is connected to the hub?  Is the hub powered?

Comment: The USB dongle is type A, so I unfortunately can't plug it directly into the computer. Also, nothing else is connected to the hub, and it does not have an external power supply, it just plugs into the thunderbolt port, and has a USB A port and an HDMI port (not used). Also, im pretty sure that the hub isn't the problem, because I've tried it with another hub and the problem persists.