# External keyboard and mouse not working for Mac

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, mouse, apple-silicon

#### My Problem

Many keystrokes on my keyboard are missed when using an external keyboard and my mouse severely lags (not just on the external monitor).

##### What I've learnt trying to debug this issue.

I've found that this certainly starts to happen after I use the built-in keyboard/trackpad. It also seems to happen after sustained use (after about an hour or two). However, I don't know whether this is because I've used the internal keyboard and forgotten.

##### My setup:

- MacBook Pro with M1 chip, running BigSur 11.5.2
- External Monitor (LG 4K, 27inch) + MacBook screen
- MS sculpt mouse and keyboard (technically bluetooth but that is handled by the dongle so BT isn't an issue.

##### Some other notes:

- The keyboard and mouse definitely work. They worked very well for the past 2 years on my Linux box.
- As the MBP only has 2 USB C ports I've had to connect the keyboard and mouse and monitor through 2 usb extenders. I haven't had any problems before with these dongles so I believe these also work.
- The keyboard and mouse dongle is USB type A and the ports are type C so I can't directly plug the dongle into the MBP.

This question seems to be fairly similar: [Intermittent lag from external keyboard and mouse](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/424613/intermittent-lag-from-external-keyboard-and-mouse)

However, it does not have an answer and I have found that this does seem to happen particularly after I use the internal keyboard and mouse.